# How to read/write files to hfs+ (journaling) partition?

Tags: macosx, hfs+

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How well is the HFS+ filesystem supported?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16811/how-well-is-the-hfs-filesystem-supported)

How to read/write files to hfs+ (journaling) partition?

Comment: [Related Bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-source-2.6.15/+bug/49052)

Comment: Have you tried to mount it manually ? It should me mountable using mount -t hfsplus device_name mount_point.

Comment: when I mount it with mount -t hfsplus device_name mount_point I got only read permissions

Comment: [Here](http://superuser.com/questions/84446/how-to-mount-a-hfs-partition-in-ubuntu-as-read-write) is something related to your query..