# How do I turn on/off HFS+ journaling?

Tags: macosx, hfs+

How can I turn on/off HFS+ journaling from Ubuntu?

Comment: related question -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/21568/how-to-read-write-files-to-hfs-journaling-partition

Answer (score 1):

From within Ubuntu, it gets real hairy. Not recommended. Follow [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1420673) lengthy forum topic. The hacks can be found [here](http://dmunsie.wordpress.com/code/hacks/)