# Mount Hfsplus partition of a disk image

Tags: mount, hfs+

I know my question is very similar to many others on this site (ex. [Mount single partition from image of entire disk (device)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69363/mount-single-partition-from-image-of-entire-disk-device)) but I have a slightly different problem during the mount of a single partition that is within a disk image (made with dd) of my MAC.

Before try to mount it, I list all the partitions inside my disk image and I read the offset of the partition. Then I try to mount the single partition with the following command and always get the same error:

```
sudo mount -t hfsplus -o loop,ro,offset=209735680 /media/dati/mac.dmg /media/mac

mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

dmesg |tail
[ 8454.285256] hfs: write access to a journaled filesystem is not supported, use the force option at your own risk, mounting read-only.
[ 8512.103020] hfs: invalid secondary volume header
[ 8512.103027] hfs: unable to find HFS+ superblock
```

The strange thing is that if I try to mount the disk image on my friend's mac I can easily mount (with a double click on it) the disk image and access to all my files.

Could this be a problem caused by the unclean hfs+ filesystem? And how can I try to resolve it?

Thanks,
Andrea

Comment: The key is that you have to [turn off journaling](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25231/how-do-i-turn-on-off-hfs-journaling) on the filesystem.

Comment: This could cause a problem if I want to mount the filesystem in rw mode. Otherwise the journaling is not a problem.

Answer (score 8):

I wanted to do the same and got the same issue with the method you used.

Here's another approach which I used successfully:

```
sudo losetup --find --show ./MacImage.img
/dev/loop9
sudo partprobe /dev/loop9
sudo mount /dev/loop9p2 /mnt/Mac-part-2
```

Hope this helps.