# Changing ownership of read-only file system

Tags: 11.10, hard-drive, read-only, macosx, hfs+

I did read the several posts available here on "changing ownership of read-only file systems" but they don't seem to help me.

My external hard drive (which I had previously formatted in OS X and used on it for over a year) doesn't allow me to copy anything from/on to it FROM my Ubuntu 11.10

It says that the `file system is read only` when I try this:

`sudo chown -R my-user-name /"Untitled 1"`

Where "Untitled 1" is the name of the external hdd.

Any suggestions?

Even getting into nautilius with `sudo nautilius` to change the ownership didn't work.

(on a side note, what is nautilius anyway? I know I can google THAT)

What should I do now?

Comment: Nautilus is the default file manager in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so after a lot of looking around and conferring with my friends, this is what worked for me.

My external hard drive has a journaled file system (hfs+). I don't quite care what that means but I had to "disable journaling".

For this I had to connect my hdd to my macbook and run the following command in it's terminal

`sudo /usr/sbin/diskutil disableJournal /Volumes/name-of-my-external-hdd`

That worked and my hdd is now read AND write enabled!!

Hope this helps someone in the future! :)

Comment: It works, but this fix is not recommended. Check this http://askubuntu.com/questions/16811/how-well-is-the-hfs-filesystem-supported

Answer (score 9):

Remount the partition (or disc) but this time with `rw` (read, write) settings.
Should be something like this:

`sudo mount -o rw,remount /"Untitled 1"`

Comment: All that in the same line? I am a completely new person to Ubuntu. Because ubuntu says that there is no command such as `remount`.

Comment: You could also try typing: sudo umount /"Untitled 1" pressing enter then typing sudo mount -o rw /"Untitled 1" and pressing enter which should have the same affect described here.

Comment: @Mykroft I tried what you said but my terminal said `mount: can't find Untitled 1 in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab` :( This is ridiculous! I am beginning to hate ubuntu.

Comment: And when you typed the above command all on one line it said no such command as remount?

Comment: DNA so add the disc to your /etc/fstab. Remember: Linux/Ubuntu is NOT difficult. It's only different. You learn and it becomes normal to you.

Comment: @Rinzwind Thanks for the encouragement. You are right, nothing is difficult only I am resistant to change. But anyway, if I may ask.... **how do I add a disk to fstab?** Isn't that creating a new partition? I don't want to mess with my file system too much as I've already deleted my .bashrc and mucked up my crontab file!!!

Comment: fstab is just a file that describes what discs to mount where it doesn't actually create anything. In any case you could try: mount -o remount,rw /"Untitled 1" the arguments may just have been in the wrong order. You'll need to remove and reinsert the usb drive first though so that it's mounted.

Comment: Sorry but I don't quite understand the language in fstab now. Its alright if no ones wants to answer this question. I'll figure it out eventually.

Answer (score 2):

Usually the cause of the fs being mounted read only is because there are errors.  You can run `dmesg` in a terminal and see if there are any errors reported, and you should check the filesystem with the disk utility.